# Drupal 7 and the Social Mention API

Tags: drupal, rest, drupal-7

I'm trying to use the example Social Mention RESTful API described here
http://code.google.com/p/socialmention-api/wiki/APIDocumentation

Simply by using the following line in my Drupal 7 module:

```
$response = drupal_http_request('http://socialmention.com/search?q=iphone+apps&f=json&t=microblogs&lang=fr');
```

The request then times out.
I've tried a variety of options, but can't seem to get a response from this API.
Any pointers are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just ended up using file_get_contents() and it works. Still not sure why drupal_http_request() failed though.